# latexmk and ps2pdf on Mac OS (TextMate)

Tags: latexmk, ps2pdf, textmate

I just recently came across a TeX file which is working with eps-files, so that latexmk first generates a `.dvi` file. The conversion to `.ps` also works great, but after that latexmk is not able to generate the pdf.

```
------------ ------------ Running 'ps2pdf "skript.ps" "skript.pdf"' ------------
 For rule 'ps2pdf', running '&do_viewfile( )' ... sh: ps2pdf: command not found Rule 'ps2pdf': File changes, etc: Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s): 'skript.ps' -
```

I noticed, that i was missing `ghostscript` and installed it (on Mac OS) using `MacPorts`.

When i call `ps2pdf script.ps` from my terminal, it works fine. Any idea, what the reason could be? It would be nice to have that handled by latexmk just to have a solid workflow (in TextMate for example).

Comment: Did you add the MacPorts path to the `PATH` environment variable in TextMate's preferences?

Comment: Good point, that I didn't mention. Yes, I did. `which ps2pdf` returns `/opt/local/bin/ps2pdf` and `/opt/local/bin` is included in the `PATH` of the textMate's preferences, i.e. that value reads `$PATH:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin`

Comment: Ah! I found the problem, and it was due to your remark. The first column in the TextMate2 Variables contains checkboxes, which activate or deactivate certain variables. Somehow I didn't remember those from TextMate1; nevertheless, despite having the PATH set correctly, actually _activating_ the variable... does the job. So if you want, you can turn that into an answer, which I would be happy to accept.